# What does this mean and how should I fix this for big files? (malloc_error_break)

Tags: c

**Problem:**

This code example searches for words and counts the number of words, and the number of unique words for larger txt files with 1000s of lines I get an error, any ideas?

**ERROR:**

```
week7_14(43430,0x1087085c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x696c617274737561: pointer being freed was not allocated
week7_14(43430,0x1087085c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

---

**Code Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 100
#define MAXWORDS 1000

int findWord(char *word[], char *temp, int index) {
    for (int i=0; i<index; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(word[i], temp) == 0) // found the word
            return 1;
    }
    return 0; // cannot find word }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char filename[MAXLEN];
    char *words[MAXWORDS] = {NULL};
    char temp[MAXLEN];
    int wordCount = 0;
    int uniqueWordCount = 0;
    int i = 0;
    // read in the filename
    printf("insert a file name: (eg. test.txt)\n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    while ((fscanf(fp, "%s", temp) == 1) && uniqueWordCount<MAXWORDS)
    {
        wordCount++; // update total number of words
    // find word in words array
        if (!findWord(words, temp, uniqueWordCount))
        {
            words[uniqueWordCount] = calloc(strlen(temp)+1,
                                            sizeof(char));
            if (words[uniqueWordCount] == NULL)
            {
                printf("calloc failed to allocate memory\n");
                return 1;
            }
            strcpy(words[uniqueWordCount], temp);
            uniqueWordCount++; // update number of unique words
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    while (i<uniqueWordCount)
    {
        free(words[uniqueWordCount]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("Total number of words = %d\n", wordCount);
    printf("Number of unique words = %d\n", uniqueWordCount);
    return 0; }
```

**Example text file that works (test.txt):**

```
Any girl jumped over one boy.
Some car skipped to some boy.
One town drove over the town.
Any town ran under some dog.
Some girl drove to a town.
The boy walked under any town.
A town jumped over any car.
Any boy jumped from a car.
A dog ran over a boy.
A girl ran to some car.
A car ran under the girl.
The car ran on any town.
One dog walked under any dog.
A car jumped on some town.
A boy ran to a boy.
The dog drove over a boy.
A boy jumped over the car.
Some car drove on some girl.
One boy drove under some girl.
A girl walked over some dog.
```

**Output:**

> insert a file name: (eg. test.txt)
>
> test.txt
>
> Total number of words = 120
>
> Number of unique words = 30

Comment: Could you explain what is unclear about the error message? It sounds reads clear and helpful to me. You seem to be freeing a pointer which was not allocated and you could use a breakpoint to debug it.

Comment: If there is any string of consecutive non-whitespace characters longer than 99 characters in your input, you may be overflowing `temp` which _might_ overwrite pointers in your `words` array and cause this problem.  As currently written, your program is vulnerable to buffer overflow.  Check that your data is not to blame here.

Comment: `free(words[uniqueWordCount])` -- you are trying to free the value after the list of _N_ unique words _N_ times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems to address, (1), you are missing the closing brace in:

```
int findWord(char *word[], char *temp, int index) {
    for (int i=0; i<index; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(word[i], temp) == 0) // found the word
            return 1;
    }
    return 0; // cannot find word }
}   /* missing closing brace */
```

(2) you have a typo and are attempting to free `words[uniqueWordCount]` instead of `words[i]`, e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; i<uniqueWordCount; i++) /* loop over each word in words */
        free(words[i]);    /* free words[i], not words[uniqueWordCount] */
```

(**note:** attempting to free `words[uniqueWordCount]` generated your error as `uniqueWordCount` is one past the last allocated pointer)

Last, you should use `int main (void)` since neither `int argc` or `char **argv` are used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Sure, we have all been there.. Good luck with your coding!

Comment: This was a teacher example too by the way. I feel this mistake was added to not give away the answer for the assignment... however this is a poor example thank you for highlighting the mistakes as its important to free the correct memory addresses.